# Node Sass generate nested CSS

Tags: node.js, node-sass

We are using Node-Sass to compile SCSS files to css.  Below is the directory structure that I am using.

[image]

**Using Node-Sass I want to generate a Dist directory where all the compiled CSS files will go to their respective directory.**

I have tried the below NPM script

```
node-sass --include-path packages/ --include-path ./node_modules --include-path packages/**/node_modules  ./packages/ -o ./build"
```

I am receiving an error "no input file found".

Any pointers of the mistake would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing multiple versions of `include-path` which isn't valide from the CLI. Use the API if multiple paths are required.

Comment: Could you please share any example or links.